# THREE.js rotate part of model

Tags: javascript, model, three.js

Is it possible to move or rotate a part of OBJ (or other format) model ? Or I have to have as many model as necessary ?

What's the best solution to do that I want ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the model consists of a single geometry, then you can't rotate part of the model, unless you manually modify the geometry itself.

If the model is represented as a hierarchy of `Object3D`s and/or `Mesh`s (see, for example, http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html), then you can rotate any branch or leaf using

```
object.rotation.set( x, y, z );
```

three.js r.69

Comment: So if I convert my obj (or export directly blender model) to an other format (like JSON), will it be possible to get an "Object3D tree" ?

Comment: If you have questions regarding your specific model, please make a new post with a live example so your issue can be reproduced.